# Averaging data of dataframe columns based on redundancy of another column

Tags: python, pandas

I want to average the data of one column in a pandas dataframe is they share the same 'id' which is stored in another column in the same dataframe. To make it simple i have:

[image]

and i want:

[image]

Were is clear that 'nx' and 'ny' columns' elements have been averaged if for them the value of 'nodes' was the same. The column 'maille' on the other hand has to remain untouched.
I'm trying with groupby but couldn't manage till now to keep the column 'maille' as it is.

Any idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html) with specify columns names in list for aggregates and assign back:

```
cols = ['nx','ny']
df[cols] = df.groupby('nodes')[cols].transform('mean')
print (df)
```

Another idea with [`DataFrame.update`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.update.html):

```
df.update(df.groupby('nodes')[cols].transform('mean'))
print (df)
```